# Customising Notification icon for Android, using Mixpanel

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, mixpanel

Using Mixpanel I am able to send out notifications directly from their control panel, however currently it uses a weirdly cropped version of the launcher icon as the notification icon.

I have seen some answers for customising the icon using a customised BroadcastReceiver, but I can't seem to get it to working in this case. Has anyone successfully managed to change the notification icon when sending directly from Mixpanel?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, there is a way to set a custom icon for android push notifications without writing your own custom broadcast receiver. Recent versions of the Mixpanel android library understand a "mp_icnm" parameter that can refer to the name of a resource in your application. The library itself is also packaged with a set of predefined icons you can use. The quick way is to put the following snippet into the "custom data" field

```
{"mp_icnm":"com_mixpanel_android_ic_megaphone"}
```

I've attached a screenshot of the Mixpanel app with a picture of the text field. You'll want to be sure that this data is entered in "Android" preview mode when you enter your data, as shown in the illustration.

[image: Illustration of custom data field in Mixpanel push notification composer screen, showing the appropriate spot for the JSON above]

You can use any drawable resource in your app for an icon- the whole list of prepackaged notification icons can be found here in the Mixpanel library, and their resource names are listed below.

- com_mixpanel_android_ic_bell
- com_mixpanel_android_ic_clipboard_checkmark
- com_mixpanel_android_ic_coin
- com_mixpanel_android_ic_flag
- com_mixpanel_android_ic_gear
- com_mixpanel_android_ic_inbox
- com_mixpanel_android_ic_megaphone
- com_mixpanel_android_ic_phone
- com_mixpanel_android_ic_rocket
- com_mixpanel_android_ic_sale_tag
- com_mixpanel_android_ic_sync
- com_mixpanel_android_ic_trophy
- com_mixpanel_android_ic_vip
- com_mixpanel_android_ic_warning

Be aware that the Mixpanel resources might be removed by your proguard configuration, so you'll want to be sure that you haven't stripped them if you want to use them.

Comment: This feature is planned to be supported more fully in the ui in future versions of the Mixpanel web application, but the library support is already live.

Comment: Worked a treat, used pretty much as you mentioned, {"mp_icnm":"ic_stat_noti_icon"} just changed the second bit to my custom icon.

Comment: hi I tried {"mp_icnm":"ic_stat_from_my_drawable"} but did not worked how come the megaphone works

Comment: Sheychan - I'm not sure off the top of my head why it doesn't work with your drawable. It might be worth commenting at the Mixpanel Github project at https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-android

Comment: I searched for it for some time, so maybe this comment helps someone: To use app drawable names for icons with Proguard to proguard config should be added: -keep class ${APP_PACKAGE_ID}.R$drawable { *; } (where ${APP_PACKAGE_ID} is your app package ID)

Answer (score 3):

To answer one aspect of @user1544797's question and in addition to @user128536's answer, you may want to let your app be responsible of configuring your notification icon and not rely on the Mixpanel preview mode. To do so, you must intercept Mixpanel broadcast by creating your own `BroadcastReceiver` that extends Mixpanel's `GCMReceiver` :

```
public class MixpanelGCMReceiver extends GCMReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        intent.putExtra("mp_icnm", "<your_icon_name>");
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }

}
```

Then declare your `BroadcastReceiver` in your *AndroidManifest.xml* file :

```
<receiver
  android:name="<your_package_name>.MixpanelGCMReceiver"
  android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

    <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Finally, @user128536 is right about warning you that Proguard is messing up with your notification icon if not managed properly (and unfortunately Mixpanel does not document how your app should handle this case). However, in addition to Proguard, there is another issue that you may need to tackle when you are using an *applicationId* that differs from your *packageName* (usually while using product flavors). In the `ResourceReader` class from Mixpanel SDK, you can see this comment :

```
MPLog.w(LOGTAG, "Can't load names for Android view ids from '" + localClassName + "', ids by name will not be available in the events editor.");
MPLog.i(LOGTAG, "You may be missing a Resources class for your package due to your proguard configuration, " +
                "or you may be using an applicationId in your build that isn't the same as the package declared in your AndroidManifest.xml file.\n" +
                "If you're using proguard, you can fix this issue by adding the following to your proguard configuration:\n\n" +
                "-keep class **.R$* {\n" +
                "    <fields>;\n" +
                "}\n\n" +
                "If you're not using proguard, or if your proguard configuration already contains the directive above, " +
                "you can add the following to your AndroidManifest.xml file to explicitly point the Mixpanel library to " +
                "the appropriate library for your resources class:\n\n" +
                "<meta-data android:name=\"com.mixpanel.android.MPConfig.ResourcePackageName\" android:value=\"YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME\" />\n\n" +
                "where YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME is the same string you use for the \"package\" attribute in your <manifest> tag."
);
```

As indicated in the above comment, if you find yourself in this situation, just add in your *AndroidManifest.xml* file the following block :

```
<meta-data
  android:name="com.mixpanel.android.MPConfig.ResourcePackageName"
  android:value="<your_package_name>" />
```

That's it, you should be done by now ;)

Comment: I like this solution but i think we can't override those icons that will come from mixpanel dashboard

Answer (score 1):

Additionally you can add small icon witch will be shown in status bar.

```
"mp_icnm_w": "your_small_icon_id"
```

It should be white with transparent bg.

Comment: what do you mean with your_small_icon_id? Not the number right? Otherwise what happens if it changes

Comment: @kingston I mean the drawable resource id (name). FE: "my_app_icon".

Comment: @kingston Smth wired happened with comment, cannot edit previous one. And If it doesn't find requested resource then it draws circled square, if I remember right.

Comment: I am passing my resource id but only a circular icon is showing.

Comment: @MohitRajput you dont have to pass the resource id. Instead add just the name without extension. Example: ic_launcher.

"mp_icnm_w": "ic_launcher"

Answer (score 1):

I'm putting this answer for all the people who are unable to figure out the perfect solution even after reading all the previous answers. I'll sum down all the key points which are required to show your app's icon when you receive the Mixpanel push.

1. If you're using **ProGuard** (in my case which I was), you need to put below settings in your **Proguard Rule** file.

```html
keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}
```

2. Add below code in your **Manifest.xml** file.

```html
<meta-data
    android:name="com.mixpanel.android.MPConfig.ResourcePackageName"
    android:value="YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME" />
```

This is the package name (`package="YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME"`) declared in your Application's manifest file (YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME is for example. Replace it with your actual Package name value). Don't mix it up with Application Id. It will not work if you put your **Application Id** here.

Point 1 & 2 is also mentioned inside the `ResourceReader` class as mentioned in one of the above answer.

```html
MPLog.w(LOGTAG, "Can't load names for Android view ids from '" + localClassName + "', ids by name will not be available in the events editor.");
MPLog.i(LOGTAG, "You may be missing a Resources class for your package due to your proguard configuration, " +
                "or you may be using an applicationId in your build that isn't the same as the package declared in your AndroidManifest.xml file.\n" +
                "If you're using proguard, you can fix this issue by adding the following to your proguard configuration:\n\n" +
                "-keep class **.R$* {\n" +
                "    <fields>;\n" +
                "}\n\n" +
                "If you're not using proguard, or if your proguard configuration already contains the directive above, " +
                "you can add the following to your AndroidManifest.xml file to explicitly point the Mixpanel library to " +
                "the appropriate library for your resources class:\n\n" +
                "<meta-data android:name=\"com.mixpanel.android.MPConfig.ResourcePackageName\" android:value=\"YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME\" />\n\n" +
                "where YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME is the same string you use for the \"package\" attribute in your <manifest> tag."
);
```

3. If you're already using a FCMPushReceiver and you want to integrate Mixpanel notification support, please follow the guidelines mentioned [here](https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-android/releases/tag/v5.5.1).

Irrespective of whether you're using a `MixpanelFCMMessagingService` or `FirebaseMessagingService`, you need to put below code inside `onMessageReceived()` section.

```
/* drawable_name is just the Drawable Name like if you app logo is app_icon, 
   use "app_icon" instead of "R.drawable.app_icon" */
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(intent.getStringExtra("mp_icnm"))) {
    intent.putExtra("mp_icnm", "drawable_name"); // mp_icnm is used for the app icon
}
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(intent.getStringExtra("mp_icnm_l"))) {
    intent.putExtra("mp_icnm_l", "drawable_name"); // mp_icnm_l is used for the large icon
}
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(intent.getStringExtra("mp_icnm_w"))) {
    intent.putExtra("mp_icnm_w", "drawable_name"); // mp_icnm_w is used for the White icon
}
```

For more info on the parameters used by Mixpanel, you can check the `parseIntent` method of `MixpanelPushNotification` class.

In case of `MixpanelFCMMessagingService`, you can get the intent in the method parameter. For `FirebaseMessagingService`, you can get the intent by doing like below -

```
final Intent intent = remoteMessage.toIntent();
```